# Android6.0以降における「barcodeScanner」のエラーについて

Tags: monaca, cordova

※ 端末でなくAndroid6.0の現象とわかりましたので件名を変更しました。

monaca にてQRコードを読み取る機能のあるアプリ作成しております。

CordovaのbarcodeScannerプラグインを使用しており、
Xperia Z2 Android5.0.2 を含む複数の端末でカメラ起動->QRコードの取得の動作を確認してます。

しかし、Xperia Z5 Compact E5823 Android6.0.1 にて、カメラ起動のタイミングで、
「Androidのカメラに問題が発生しました。」というMonacaデバッガーのアラートが表示され、
エラー終了します。
また、apkファイルにしてテストしても同様のエラーとなります。

各バージョンは以下のとおりです。
Cordovaバージョン: 6.2.0
BarcodeScanner: v1.0.2

エラーを回避する方法はございますでしょうか。

Comment: Android SDK build target が 23以上なら Runtime Permissionが原因の気がします。 https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/291#issuecomment-243704204 が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Android6.0以降はカメラto（写真を保存する場合）ストレージの権限の取得が必要のようです。BarcodeScanner.requestCameraPermission を実行すればよさそうですが、monacaのプラグインのバージョンでは動かないようです？？単なる私の誤りかも知れないのでもう少し確認してみます。

Comment: barcodeScannerプラグイン単体の場合Permissionが取れないようで、一度Cameraプラグインで権限を取得したあとだと、barcodeScannerも動作するようになりました。

Comment: barcodeScannerの最新が今6.0.xのようですね……(monaca版はどうなってるんだろこのあたり……) 1.0.3で対応されてる様子一切なし……(PR送りたい)